# Inserting text from multiple cells into email title

Tags: excel, vba

I want to send an email with a table from Excel.

I want to insert text strings from multiple cells into the email title.

I have code from someone else's form that I'm trying to modify.

The title doesn't work, but as far is I'm aware the rest does.

```vb
Sub SendEmailFleet()
    '
    ' SendEmailFleet Macro
    '
    Dim olapp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olemail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olinsp As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim wddoc As Word.Document
    
    Set olapp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olemail = olapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    With olemail
        .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
        .Display
        
        .To = "example@example.com"
        .Subject = "Salgsmail" & " " & .Range("C25:D25") & " " & .Range("C23:D23")
        
        Set olinsp = .GetInspector
        Set wddoc = olinsp.WordEditor
        
        wddoc.Range.InsertBefore "     "
            
        Sheet1.Activate
        Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
        
        wddoc.Range(3, 3).Paste
        
    End With
        
End Sub
```

Comment: `.Range("C25:D25")` and `.Range("C23:D23")` first need to refer to an actual `Worksheet`. Currently they refer to `With olemail`.
 Then, they are implicitly 2D arrays, which you can't concatenate using `&` (Type Mismatch). One option is to concatenate each cell individually.

Comment: Thanks, how do I concatenate them individually?

Comment: `.Range("C25").Value & .Range("D25").Value`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution, using a mix of the above:

```
.subject = "Salgsmail" & " " & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C25").Value & " " & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C23").Value
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the text from the Range

```
WorksheetFunction.TextJoin(" ", True, Sheet1.Range("C25:D25"))
```

So your `.subject` should be like this:

```
.Subject = "Salgsmail" & " " & WorksheetFunction.TextJoin(" ", True, Sheet1.Range("C25:D25")) & " " & WorksheetFunction.TextJoin(" ", True, Sheet1.Range("C23:D23"))
```

Comment: Side note: earlier versions of Excel don't support `TextJoin`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. The macro doesn't function and the line is still highlighted in the debugger. I'm using excel 2016, is that too old?